# How to intercept app write to database?

Tags: android, database, intercept

how can I write an app that intercept another app that writes to its own database?
Example:
Normal way: App ---> Database
What I want to do: App ---> My app (change input) ---> Database
The database is in the app data folder.
Is it possible to do? (With root access)

Comment: It very much depends on the app that you are receiving information from, can you be more specific ?

Comment: I've no control over the app, I must intercept its write to the database but I think nor Xposed nor Cydia Substrate can do this.